# `rsync src/ des` vs `rsync src des` not working with `--files-from`

Tags: rsync

I have the following folder structure

```
src
├── sub0
├── sub1
└── sub2
```

and I use the command `rsync -avh src/ des` in order to copy the content of src inside a folder named des.

I am trying to reproduce the same behaviour using `--files-from`, so I created a file named `list.txt`, containing the string `src/` and I am using the command

```
rsync -arvh --files-from='./list.txt' . des
```

Anyway what I get is the following folder structure, which is not what I what

```
des
└── src
    ├── sub0
    ├── sub1
    └── sub2
```

How can I get the result that I am able to achieve with the first method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the last slash like this :

```
rsync -avh src/ dest/
```

It's the normal way to do the rsync without recreating the folder like you show in your test

You can even add "cool" options of rsync (replacing verbose with progress) :

```
rsync -ah --stats --progress src/ dest/
```

Comment: I need to do this using `--files-from`, it works perfectly with one inline file description like your (and my) first command

Comment: btw, thank you for the `--stats` trick ;)

Comment: Ok sorry... You missunderstand my answer. The important part is the last slash (to specify : inside this directory).

Comment: Actually, I do not feel any difference between `rsync -avh src/ des/` and `rsync -avh src/ des`, only if I change the first slash

Comment: Maybe it makes difference when using `--delete-after` or `--delete-before`